# VLC: Looping an MPEG-TS file with multiple video PIDs

Tags: loops, vlc, mpeg, transport-stream

I'm simulating a bunch of DASH and HLS live streams using static TS (MPEG Transport Stream) files that are looped, packaged, and served as follows:

```
cvlc --loop myfile.ts  -->  Shaka packager  -->  NGINX webserver
```

The TS file was created using `ffmpeg` to turn the input 1080p content (myfile.mov) into 1 audio stream and 3 video streams: 720p, 480p and 360p.  The resulting file was checked to ensure it was correctly constructed.

`cvlc` is used to loop the TS since it correctly handles PCR & PTS updating for each loop, making the video "look" live.

Here's my `cvlc` command:

```
cvlc myfile.ts --sout udp:127.0.0.1:9876 --repeat --loop --sout-all --sout-keep
```

My problem is that `cvlc` is ***randomly*** renumbering and reordering the video PIDs, so the packager can't put the right resolution in the right place for adaptive streaming.

How do I loop an MPEG-TS and have `cvlc` leave the PIDs alone (or at least keep them in numerical order), and only update the PCR/PTS/DTS during each loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use ***both*** `--sout-ts-es-id-pid` and `--ts-es-id-pid` to ensure PIDs are not changed by VLC at either the input or output stages.

Final command:

```
cvlc myfile.ts --sout udp:127.0.0.1:9876 --sout-ts-es-id-pid --ts-es-id-pid --repeat --loop --sout-all  --sout-keep
```